# Field error for django Prefetch() while resolving ManyToMany relations

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm, prefetch

Here are my models:

```
class Element(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='element_creator', on_delete=CASCADE)
    element_type = models.ForeignKey('ElementType', on_delete=CASCADE)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modif_date = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True


class ElementWorkingSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modif_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    elements = models.ManyToManyField(Element,
                                      through='ElementSet2Element',
                                      through_fields=('element_working_set', 'elements'),
                                      )

    class Meta:
        managed = True


class ElementSet2Element(models.Model):
    element_working_set = models.ForeignKey('ElementWorkingSet',
                                            on_delete=CASCADE)
    elements = models.ForeignKey(Element, on_delete=CASCADE)
    active = models.IntegerField()
    element_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    approver = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='+', on_delete=CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
```

I'm extracting a list of ElementWorkingSet, and want to display child Elements with `element_owner` and `approver` from the `ElementSet2Element` table.

At first, I was performing many relations without using prefetch_related, but it turned out to be extremely inefficient. Until the time when I needed the `element_owner` and `approver`, the response time was decent. But extracting those fields made it very slow.

I'm trying to modify my query, to perform more efficient query by using following query:

```
query = ElementWorkingSet.objects.filter(
            project__id=project_id, active=True).select_related(
        'owner'
        ).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'elements',
                queryset=ElementSet2Element.objects.select_related(
                    'elements',
                    'approver',
                    'element_owner'
                ),
            ),
        )
```

The problem is, that Django returns following error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'elementworkingset' into field. Choices are: active, approver, approver_id, id, element_owner, element_owner_id, element_working_set, element_working_set_id, elements, elements_id
```

I'm not using `elementworkingset` as a variable anywhere. It actually doesn't occur anywhere within my project. After debugging I've noticed, that it comes from the `ElementWorkingSet` model name.

I have no idea why it happens, and what I can do to fix it. I'm using Django 1.9 and Python 3.6 with MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you have declared

```
elements = models.ManyToManyField(
                          Element,
                          through='ElementSet2Element',
                          through_fields=('element_working_set', 'elements'))`
```

It is perfectly correct, however, when you pass `'elements'` to `Prefetch`,
it determines this is relation to Element model, not ElementSet2Element as you expected (yes, it does pretty smart things). So, the backward field name for Element is `elementworkingset`, because you haven't declared other via `related_query_name` or `related_name` in your `models.ManyToManyField` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name)). Then you pass `ElementSet2Element` queryset and django tries to find `elementworkingset` in it. Since you have no such field in `ElementSet2Element`, it fails.

So, instead of `'elements'` you should pass `'elementset2element_set'` to `Prefetch`

Comment: That's it! Thank you.